# MySQL select row if it's specified in another row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have one table with multiple rows where some rows are the other's "children".

The table looks like this:

> id, name, parent, slug

Sample data:

```
1, Jack, NULL, jack 
2, John, NULL, john 
3, Mike, jack, mike
```

The query should return jack, because it's mike's parent.

so I want to return the rows that are specified in other rows as "parents". I'm really new to MySQL and I have no idea how to do it.

Unfortunately I didn't get lucky with Google too because I'm not sure how to ask exactly.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Comment: This is a really bad table design - the parent should be the `id` field, not the `name`.

Comment: The table is a bit more complex, but I made it simpler here so you can understand my question easier.

Comment: @Alex Please provide the actual table structure.  Is `Parent` actually referencing the `name` field, as you've defined, or is it actually referencing the `id` field?  If it's using the `Name` field, you will definitely want to consider refactoring this table.

Comment: The parent is a `slug` (part of URL) field, which is unique and generated from the name. Is there any reason I should use the ID instead? I found it easier to use the slug.

Comment: @Alex Yes, you should use the `ID` for the parent reference.  That's the identifying field for the record.  Consider:  what would happen if there were two people named `Jack`?

Comment: The `slug` field is set as unique, so this isn't going to be a problem. I was using `ID` initially, but it's easier with `slug`. Is there other reason I should still go with `ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want rows that have children:

```
select distinct p.*
from table p join
     table c
     on p.name = c.parent;
```

Or, similarly:

```
select p.*
from table p
where exists (select 1 from table c where c.parent = p.name);
```

Note:  `table` means put in your table there.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name AS t1 WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FORM table_name AS t2 WHERE t2.parent = t1.name) > 0
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table_name AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN table_name AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.name
    GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: I don't want to get the children, but the parents (rows that have children).

Comment: Updated, try this one

Answer (score 1):

```
select parent_person.* 
from person
    inner join person as parent_person on parent_person.name = person.parent
```